# C# parameters in a javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to call a JS function with a C# parameter.

This is inside a HTML table.

```
    <td onclick="OpenWindow(<%= cbYear.SelectedValue%>, 2);return false;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
```

The JS function:

```
function OpenWindow(annee, mois) {

    //Call existing global function to obtain a reference to the window manager
    var oManager = GetRadWindowManager();
    //Show a particular existing window
    oManager.open(null, "RadWindow1");
}
```

the problem is simply it does not work anymore with paramaters( it works perfectly without)...
Does anyone know why, thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the produced source, is it what you expect?

Comment: the produced source is this :

<td onclick="OpenWindow(&lt;%= cbYear.SelectedValue%>, 2);return false;">0</td>

Comment: It clearly does not interpret my first parameter

Comment: this looks to me like it would work. What error are you getting, what type is cbyear.selectedvalue, what have you tried, etc?

Comment: cbyear is a combobox.
I haven't tried anything else .

Comment: This may sound dumb but the the combobox and the HTML table are within the same ASPX file right? And you are viewing the page through a server (not just loading the aspx file into your browser).

Comment: The only time I normally see something like this is if the HTML control (in this case the `<td>`) is set to `runat="server"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I've seen the `<%=...%>` be rendered into the browser is when the HTML control (in this case `<td>`) is turned into a server-side control using the `runat="server"` attribute.

**IF** this is the case, I would suggest that you place the following in your code-behind file (assuming you have a code-behind), and remove the `onclick` from the markup

```
myTdCell.Attributes("onclick") = string.Format("OpenWindow({0},2);", cbYear.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to place quotes around your dynamic value:

```
<td onclick="OpenWindow('<%= cbYear.SelectedValue%>', 2);return false;">
        &nbsp;
</td>
```

Otherwise, js might try to interpret the *value* as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<td onclick='<%= "OpenWindow(" + cbYear.SelectedValue + ", 2);return false;" %>'>
        &nbsp;
</td>
```

Or this:

```
<td id="td1" runat="server">
   &nbsp;
</td>
```

And from code do:

```
td1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "OpenWindow(" + cbYear.SelectedValue + ", 2);return false;");
```